# dplyr use n() within summarize to get row count of different grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame includes `region`, `date` (by day), and general response data for a survey. I have grouped and summarized by `region` and `date`, so that I have a daily count of completed surveys (looking at a boolean `Finished` variable). If I use `n()`, I get a total for a `region` on that `date` (since I grouped the data frame by both of these).

I would like to add the total based on only `region`, across all dates. Is this possible using the dplyr methods? I have currently calculated the `region` totals, and after summarizing my table, have manually added a column using `case_when` to add the `region` totals. The goal is to make cumulative completion percentages per region in `ggplot`.

Is my approach the only way, or is it possible to use dplyr methods to remove a grouping level when calculating `n()`?

Example below. `DailyCompeted` is the sum of `boolean` `Finished`, and `total` is giving the total count for that day in that region. My goal is for `total` to be the sum of that column (`92`), per `region` in every row.

```
x %>% group_by(Region, EndDate) %>% summarize(DailyCompleted=sum(Finished), total=n())

Region EndDate    DailyCompleted total
   <fct>  <date>              <int> <int>
 1 AMER   2019-04-29              0     1
 2 AMER   2019-04-30              0     1
 3 AMER   2019-05-02              1     1
 4 AMER   2019-05-03              1     1
 5 AMER   2019-05-06             40    54
 6 AMER   2019-05-07             12    17
 7 AMER   2019-05-08              4     7
 8 AMER   2019-05-09              3     5
 9 AMER   2019-05-10              3     4
10 AMER   2019-05-12              1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reaggregate the summarized data by `Region`, and then join it bak to the data frame that has been aggregated by `EndDate`.

```
textFile <- "Region EndDate    DailyCompleted total
 AMER   2019-04-29              0     1
 AMER   2019-04-30              0     1
 AMER   2019-05-02              1     1
 AMER   2019-05-03              1     1
 AMER   2019-05-06             40    54
 AMER   2019-05-07             12    17
 AMER   2019-05-08              4     7
 AMER   2019-05-09              3     5
 AMER   2019-05-10              3     4
AMER   2019-05-12              1     1"

regionDay <- read.table(text = textFile,header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
regionDay %>% group_by(Region) %>%
     summarise(regionDay,region_total = sum(total)) %>%
     inner_join(regionDay,.)
region_tot
```

...and the output is:

```
   Region    EndDate DailyCompleted total region_total
1    AMER 2019-04-29              0     1           92
2    AMER 2019-04-30              0     1           92
3    AMER 2019-05-02              1     1           92
4    AMER 2019-05-03              1     1           92
5    AMER 2019-05-06             40    54           92
6    AMER 2019-05-07             12    17           92
7    AMER 2019-05-08              4     7           92
8    AMER 2019-05-09              3     5           92
9    AMER 2019-05-10              3     4           92
10   AMER 2019-05-12              1     1           92
>
```

Comment: Thank you! So not really possible without doing a join, was wondering if I could ungroup one level before summarizing but this is also straight forward anyway.